# Copy files from source to destination but deleting any files in destination but NOT in source

Tags: bash

So I am cloning one folder to another using Bash. Currently my script is recursive and noclobber. Works great.

```
!cp -r -n /content/gdrive/Shared\ drives/Source/. /content/gdrive/Shared\ drives/Destination
```

This copies just fine. I just am looking for a way to delete any files if NOT on the Source drive but IS on the Destination drive. Maybe I need an entirely different script method?

Edit. I ended up using

```
!rsync -v -r --ignore-existing /gdrive/Shared\ drives/Source/. /gdrive/Shared\ drives/Destination --delete
```

Seems to be working for now. I was using -u but it seemed to be re-copying files just because the date changed, not the file itself. Thanks 1218985 for the help!

Comment: Look into `rsync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this with `rsync`:

```sh
rsync --delete "/content/gdrive/Shared\ drives/Source/" "/content/gdrive/Shared\ drives/Destination/"
```

Comment: If syncing between local directories then adding compression is probably doing nothing except slowing it down.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.